# Toss a fair coin $2n$ times. You earn $1$ for each heads, and lose $1$ for each tails. Final net return is $0$, and net return is never negative .

Tags: probability

Let me make myself more clear:

We flip a coin $2n$ times, and we earn 1 point if it's a head and lose one point when it's a tail. Now the question is how many ways are there such that after flipping the $2n$ times, the total score is $0$ and we have never reached the negative side.(We can easily get the probability after that).

For example: if $n = 2$, we can have to ways:

head->tail->head->tail

head->head->tail->tail

What I am thinking is that I can use recursive way to get that:

Define a function $f(n,x)$, where n is the number of flipping and x is "the distance to the desired point". For example, if we say $f(2,-1)$, that means we flip the coin twice and reach 1 point lower compared to the current position without passing point lower than "-1" point.(That might a little confusing). For example, if we want to find $f(2,0)$, we must win at the first time, then we should go to the position lower than that in one step, that is $f(1,-1)$.

I have reduced the problem into a recursive problem:
$$f(n,x) = f(n-1,x-1)+f(n-1,x+1)$$
while:
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}， f(1,0)=0,f(1,k) = 0,f(1,-1)=1,f(1,-k)=0$$

I have written a code for this but I really wonder about the general formula.

```
def f(n,x) :
    if(n == 1 and x == -1):
        return 1
    if(n == 1 and x != -1):
        return 0
    if(x == 0):
        return f(n-1,x-1)
    if(x<0):
        return f(n-1,x-1)+f(n-1,x+1)
```

How can I solve a recursive problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this supposed to model an actual gambling situation? [I ask since in those one would expect net winnings to sometime during a run to be negative.]

Comment: It is currently not clear to me what is the question. Are you asking how many of the $2^{2n}$ ways in which the coin could land satisfy the two conditions (net result 0 and also never negative in an earlier stage)?

Comment: Your recursion $f(n,x) = f(n-1,x-1)+f(n-1,x+1)$ applies when $x\ge 0$.  You have $f(n,x)=0$ when $n < 0$  since *"net return is never negative"*.  Your $f(1,-1)=1$ looks inconsistent with *"net return is never negative"* so I think you start with $f(0,0)=1$ but $f(n,0)=0$ when $n \not=0$ . Are you looking for $f(2n,0)$, a count rather than a probability? If so, the answer is related to Catalan numbers and will be a duplicate of other questions here.

Comment: Sorry that I might didn't explain myself clearly enough. I have modified the question again. In fact, the useful range of x is negative integer representing the distance to the 0 point but I think my notion might be a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

You have a random walk $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_{2n}$ where each $X_i\in\{-1,+1\}$.
You want to count $T$, the number of ways such that $S_{2n}=0$ and $S_i>-1$ for each $i=0,1,2,\dots,2n$. Then, necessarily, $S_{2n-1}=1$.

Let $(t,x)$ denote the point in time $t$ and the value $x$ of the random walk. Then $T$ equals the number of paths from $(-1,-1)$ to $(2n-1,1)$ such that they never revisit the axes $x=-1$. In turn, this equals the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2)$ such that they never revisit the axes $x=0$.

By the [Ballot Theorem](https://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ebreed/MATH671/lecture2corrected.pdf) the number of such paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2)$ is $ \frac{2}{2n} N_{2n}(0,2)$ where $N_{m}(u,v)$ is the number of paths from $(0,u)$ to $(m,v)$.

In our case, $N_{2n}(0,2)=\binom{2n}{n-1}$ as we must have $n+1$ steps up and $n-1$ steps down to hit $2$, so your final answer is
$$
T=\frac1{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}.
$$